# Object from NSUserDefaults releasing?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad

So I have a username saved in the UserDefaults.  For some reason, I am experiencing some strange behavior.

I have a data controller that goes and fetches some data from the server based on the user name.

```
NSUserDefaults *prefs = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
NSLog(@"NSUserDefaults dump: %@", [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] dictionaryRepresentation]);

userID = [prefs stringForKey:@"username"];
```

This works fine for the first few times, but after I do some random stuff and go back to try and reload the views, it crashes.  It says:

```
-[CFString retain]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x4b18ff0
```

This is strange because it is stopping on the NSLog line.  Has anyone seen this before or know why it may be happening??

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How you defined your userID? If it's a property with a retain attribute you should call

`self.userID = [prefs stringForKey:@"username"];`

this way your string will be retained automatically. The string that is returned from stringForKey is autoreleased.

Comment: Yeah that would appear to have been the problem.  It isn't crashing anymore.  Sigh, looks like that slight oversight is what was giving me the headaches.  Thanks for the help Nava.  :)

Comment: I will as soon as I can lol.  It makes you wait like 5 minutes.  It was just too fast! ;)

Answer (score 0):

stringForKey returns an autorelease object which you aren't retaining, it's probably released as soon as that method finishes.

You need to retain that string either by doing so manually or using a property declaration with the retain setting.

And then you need to release it at some point (at least in dealloc)

Comment: Yup, that's what I had to do.  Didn't realize it wasn't being retained.  By not explicitly saying self.userID, it wasn't being saved.  Thanks for the response though.